# how to make this password generator generate random length password

Tags: bash

im new to bash scripting and need help with this.
i have this password generator script and it generates 8 character long password. I've been trying to make it generate random length but couldn't do it. Can someone with bash scripting knowledge give me some suggestion on how i could do this?

Here is my script

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
num=("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "7" "8" "9")
special=("@" "#" "$" "%" "*" "-" "+")
upper=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
lower=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
length=(0 1 2 3 4 5 7 8)
length2=${#length[*]} #${lower[$((RANDOM%length2))])
lower2=${#lower[*]}   #${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}
upper2=${#upper[*]}   #${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}
num2=${#num[*]}     #${num[$((RANDOM%num2))]}
special2=${#special[*]} #${special[$((RANDOM%special2))]}
abc=`#${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}`

echo "$word${special[$((RANDOM%special2))]}${num[$((RANDOM%num2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}${lower[$((RANDOM%lower2))]}${upper[$((RANDOM%upper2))]}$length" | fold -w 1 | shuf | tr -d '\n'
echo

fi
```

Comment: First initialize `$RANDOM` with a random value: `RANDOM=$(tr -dc '0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c 4)`

Answer (score 1):

Bash's `$RANDOM` can't be used to generate random passwords because it's too predictable.

To generate a more secure password of a pseudo-random length, use something like

```
tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9@#$^*-+' < /dev/urandom | head -c $((RANDOM % 8 + 16))
```

Of course I appreciate that you just want to do this for learning purposes, but people who later google "how to generate random length passwords in bash" shouldn't get an insecure algorithm as their first result.

Comment: what does % 8 + 16 do?

Comment: `%` is [remainder after division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). RANDOM%8 will give a number betwen 0 and 7 inclusive, and then you add 16 to get a number between 16 and 23.

Comment: can i make it so that it only outputs 1 special character?